# Creating multiple databases in H2

Tags: database, unit-testing, junit, h2

We are using H2 as test database for junittest suite. The actual application has tables in multiple databases like db1.s1.table1 and db2.s1.table2  (in other words database.schema.tablename) . To replicate that functionality we need to create two databases db1 and db2 and then create schema and tables accordingly. Also we have a dbscript.sql which loads all data before running test suite.

Please let us know if there is a way to create multiple databases in H2. If yes, what will be the exact command to do that as part of the script.

Since H2 creates the database specified as part of jdbc URL. Is there a way to specify multiple databases as part of URL so we can have them created.

Comment: Why do you need multiple databases? Using multiple schemas should be enough in the most cases.